# How to fix PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', on laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cpanel

I have hosted by project on shared hosting where my 'app' folder i outside public_html The php version is 7.3.5, the issue i am having is.. i am have created a cron job to automatically backup the project database but i keep getting this error on my logs;

```php
[08-Jun-2019 21:04:01 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /home/username/app-folder/vendor/zendframework/zend-diactoros/src/functions/marshal_uri_from_sapi.php on line 83
```

I am using spatie/laravel-backup.

My cron is set as

```
*   *   *   *   *   php /home/username/app-folder/artisan backup:run
```

Comment: Sounds like CLI version is different. Whats the code, and what does the version come back as if you run `php --version`?

Comment: That was what I initially thought so i created a route; ```Route::get('phpinfo', function () {
    return phpinfo();
});``` and am getting PHP Version 7.3.5

Comment: When running in command line as well as web? CRON uses CLI so you must verify both versions are the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked that file at line 83?

I did, on [Github](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-diactoros/blob/master/src/functions/marshal_uri_from_sapi.php), I see the only question mark on that line is a `?int` in the method signature.

I googled for 15seconds and found that it's a [new feature](https://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php) of PHP 7.1 . So I checked [composer.json](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-diactoros/blob/master/composer.json) of that package and see that it requires `"php": "^7.1"`.

Are you sure you are running PHP 7.3.5 on that machine? Please put a `phpinfo(); exit();` in your `public/index.php` and double check because that error is a symptom you are running a version of php lower than 7.1

Answer (score 1):

The error represents an issue with **PHP scripts written for PHP 7.X** and above **that use an older version of PHP**.

The feature which is used is called a ***Null Coalesce Operator***.

You can read more about it from PHP's official documentation here - https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op

The cron which you're using is invoking the php binary directly, which is the default version set to be used by WHM/cPanel

If you know the direct path to your PHP binary you can directly call it when setting up your cron like:

```
*   *   *   *   *   php /home/username/app-folder/artisan backup:run
```

For servers without CloudLinux:

```
*   *   *   *   *   /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/bin/php /home/username/app-folder/artisan backup:run
```

For servers with CloudLinux:

```
*   *   *   *   *   /opt/alt/php70/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/app-folder/artisan backup:run
```

*Note: You can change hte php70 string in the two example paths above with any other PHP 7.X version installed, for PHP 7.1 - php71 etc..